# Error installing pyMPI on CentOS 5.9

Tags: python-2.7, centos, installation, mpi

I'm trying to make a local install of pyMPI on a server running CentOS 5.9 (i.e. I don't have sudo privileges). The ./configure step completes successfully, however there a lot of "no"s. When i try running make i get a lot of "deprecated" error messages and the process exits with error code 2. Can anyone help me with this please?

The results of running

```
./configure --prefix=/inside/home/aarjunrao/apps/py_modules/pyMPI
```

are as follows

[./configure output](http://pastebin.com/AkQgTneC)

I then run make, which gives the output

[make output](http://pastebin.com/VZjFbihd)

Thanks in advance,

Arjun

Answer (score 0):

From your make output, line 305:

`pyMPI_util.c:22:31: error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory`

Is NumPy installed on this system? If not, that's probably your problem...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but numpy is installed on the system! It's also on my python path. Does it need to be on my $PATH variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option in the configure process

```
./configure --prefix=/inside/home/aarjunrao/apps/py_modules/pyMPI --with-includes='-I/[path_to_numpy]/core/include'
```

In my case, it is

```
--with-includes='-I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include'
```

Doing that, you don't need to modify the system PATH.